# Grails Spock testing Controller and service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

Hi I have a controller called ApiController which uses a service called ApiService like so:

```
def createCategory(){
        def jsonObj = request.JSON
        jsonObj.each{ key, value ->
            params.put(key,value)
        }
        render apiService.createCategory(params)
}
```

Which works fine. 
But I cannot seem to write a test for it.

This is how far I have got:

```
@TestFor(ApiController)
@Mock([Category,ApiService])   
class CategorySpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test"() {

        setup:
        def apiService = Mock(ApiService)

        when:
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.requestMethod = 'POST'
        params.categoryID = 'test'

        controller.createCategory()

        then:
        println(response)
        1==1

    }
```

From this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method createCategory() on null object
```

This is obviously because It cannot see my apiService bean. So My question is how do i do this in Spock?

Comment: how is your controller which conntaining createCategory() looks...or give detailed structure of that controoler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most likely to do with the `Transactional bug` : https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1501

```
ApiService apiService = new ApiService()
controller.apiService = apiService
apiService.transactionManager = Mock(PlatformTransactionManager) { getTransaction(_) >> Mock(TransactionStatus) }
```

This is a temporary fix (as per the bug report comment) ... this has worked for me :)

Comment: Hate this bug... but I know they've got a lot on their plate!

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd never find out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in Grails 2.4, without annotation `@Mock` on the spec class:

```
when:
    def serviceMock = mockFor(ApiService)
    serviceMock.demand.createCategory { def params -> "output sample" }
    controller.apiService = serviceMock.createMock()
    controller.createCategory()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ApiService` is mocked sucessfully in the test but how are you providing the mock to the controller? Unit specs are deprived of DI, you cannot expect it to autowire. Therefore,

```
setup:
controller.apiService = Mock(ApiService)
```